# Map inside fragment list

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am making an app and I am using only single activity and more fragment and when I am going one fragment to another fragment which having list and every item having map button when I am clicking on it first time then it is opening map but when again we clicking on map button it is giving gsm fragment inflating error.
I don't know why it is giving this error while first time it is creating map after close map again open we get error.

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_map);
                    dialog.setTitle("Map");

                    dialog.show();
                    Button closeButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mr_close);
                    final LinearLayout frg=(LinearLayout)dialog.findViewById(R.id.frg);
                    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            frg.removeAllViews();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });


<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/frg"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".8"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/mr_close"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"

            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:text="close"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please add full code for understanding

Comment: you should pass the latitude and longitude of whatever you want to show on the map to the fragment using the arguments and then show them on the map

Answer (score 0):

This is due to duplicate fragment, remove it on closeButton click

```
try {
        android.app.Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (fragment != null) {
            android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove map from inflated list item when your **ListFragment** has removed. Also you can check your map is inflated before in `onCreate` of your **ListFragment** and remove map before inflating **ListFragment** layout.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    if (supportMapFragment != null)
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(supportMapFragment).commit();
}
```

Remove map while destroying fragment. Like,

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
    if (supportMapFragment != null && getActivity() != null) {
        try {
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(supportMapFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```